# Calculating next frame in conways game of life using java

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

trying to create a Conways Game of life, but apparently the shapes are not like they have to be. Perhaps someone can help me find the issue.

For example the glider :

```
- X - - - - 
- - X X - - 
- X X - - -
- - - - - -
```

becomes this

```
- - X X - - 
- X - - - - 
X X X - - - 
- X X X - -
```

but should be like this :

```
- - X - - -
- - - X - -
- X X X - -
- - - - - -
```

And my code looks like this

```
public Frame(int x, int y) {

     setWidth(x);
     setHeight(y);

     if (x<1)
         frame = null;
      else if (y<1)
         frame = null;
      else {

       frame = new String [x][y];

         for (int i=0; i<frame.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<frame[i].length; j++) {

               frame [i][j] = DEAD;
            }
         }
      } // else
   } // construktor


 public Integer getNeighbourCount(int x, int y) {

    Frame cell = new Frame(getHeight(), getWidth());
    int counter = 0;

    if(frame[x][y].equals(ALIVE))
    {
        counter = counter - 1;
    }
    for(int i=x-1; i<=x+1;i++){

        if(i<frame.length && i>0){

            for(int j=y-1; j<=y+1;j++){

                if(j<frame[i].length && j>0){

                    if (frame[i][j]==ALIVE) {
                        counter++;

                    }

                }
        }
        }
    }

    return counter;

}



public Frame nextFrame() {

    // Returns next frame


    Frame cell = new Frame(getWidth(), getHeight());
    //cell.frame = new String[getWidth()][getHeight()];

    for(int i = 0; i < frame.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j <frame[i].length;j++){

            int n = getNeighbourCount(i,j);

                if(cell.frame[i][j]==null) {

                    cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
                }
               if (isAlive(i, j) && n < 2 || n > 3) {
                   cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
               }
               if (isAlive(i, j) && n == 3 || n == 2){
                   cell.frame[i][j] = ALIVE;
               }
               if(!isAlive(i, j) && n == 3) {          
                   cell.frame[i][j] = ALIVE;
               }
               if(isAlive(i, j) && n > 3){

                   cell.frame[i][j] = DEAD;
               }

               frame[i][j] = cell.frame[i][j];
        }

        }

    cell.toString();
    return cell;
}

    `
```

Full code http://pastebin.com/LMwz724H

Comment: General points: `if (i < frame.length && i > 0)` probably should be `if (i < frame.length && i >= 0)` - note the `>=`. This issue appears twice. Also `x` and `y` are not used in any valuable way in `nextFrame`. Also why the `counter = counter - 1;`` in `getNeighborCount`? Also you mix `equals` and `==` when comparing against `ALIVE`.

Comment: Your primary problem is that you a confusing `x` with `y` while using `i` and `j`. Look closely at all uses of `i` and `j` and make sure you are iterating in the right direction.

Comment: Well i´ve heard that string sshould be compraed with equals and `counter = counter - 1;` so it doesnt count the point it self in the counter. The neighbours counter works perfect the main issue is in the nextFrame method i think or the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works - using an `enum` for each cell and getting the i/j and x/y stuff right (I think). It certainly generates the correct first iteration:

```
static class GameOfLife {

    final int w;
    final int h;
    State[][] frame;

    enum State {

        Dead, Alive;
    }

    public GameOfLife(int w, int h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        frame = new State[h][w];
    }

    public void alive(int x, int y) {
        frame[y][x] = State.Alive;
    }

    public void tick() {
        frame = nextGeneration();
    }

    private int surroundingPopulation(int x, int y) {
        int pop = 0;
        for (int i = y - 1; i <= y + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = x - 1; j <= x + 1; j++) {
                // On frame - vertically.
                if ((i >= 0 && i < h)
                        // On frame horizontally.
                        && (j >= 0 && j < w)
                        // Alive
                        && (frame[i][j] == State.Alive)
                        // Not the center.
                        && (i != y || j != x)) {
                    pop += 1;
                }
            }

        }
        return pop;
    }

    private State[][] nextGeneration() {
        State[][] next = new State[h][w];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                int pop = surroundingPopulation(x, y);
                // Any live cell
                if (frame[y][x] == State.Alive) {
                    if (pop < 2) {
                        // ... with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
                        next[y][x] = State.Dead;
                    } else if (pop > 3) {
                        // ... with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
                        next[y][x] = State.Dead;
                    } else {
                        // ... with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
                        next[y][x] = State.Alive;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
                    if (pop == 3) {
                        next[y][x] = State.Alive;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (State[] row : frame) {
            for (State c : row) {
                s.append(c == State.Alive ? "X" : " ");
            }
            s.append("\r\n");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
}

public void test() {
    GameOfLife g = new GameOfLife(6, 6);
    g.alive(1, 0);
    g.alive(2, 1);
    g.alive(3, 1);
    g.alive(1, 2);
    g.alive(2, 2);
    System.out.println("Before:\r\n" + g);
    g.tick();
    System.out.println("After:\r\n" + g);
}
```

Comment: Well thanks but im pretty sure its not about the enum, more likely about my constructor :)

Comment: @JuuriPeeter - I agree - your issue is with inconsistent use of x/y and i/j for across/down. If you check each one carefully you will find at least one place where you have mistakenly swapped the orientation. Try creating your frame as a 6 x 4 - each mistake will pop out as an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: @JuuriPeeter - The discipline you need to grow is to always walk **down then across** with 2d arrays. This feels strange because you then access your arrays as `[y][x]` which feels all wrong but it avoids many other issues.

Comment: Wow its really confusing actually, but i got the point now thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are copying the new value as you iterate through the loop. This means neighbours are using the value from the next tick rather than the current one.

You can fix this by waiting until you calculated all new values in your new frame: `cell.frame` and then iterate through the frame again and copy from `cell.frame` to `frame`.

An alternative (better in my view) is to have away of cloning a frame during construction. Then you could change your `nextFrame` method to create a clone of `frame` and use the clone to set the new values in `frame`.

Comment: you mean using recursion in the nextFrame method?

Comment: A buffer is easier.  Recursion is a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the DEAD and ALIVE frames while you iterate through the grid. You need to store the coordinates which should die or become alive and perform that afterwards.

Store the coordinates in two ArrayLists (dead, alive). The first and second position is the x and y axis, and change those coordinates according to whether they should become alive or not.

Comment: No he's not - he's changing `cell.frame` which is a new `Frame`.

Comment: Yes thats true OldCurmudgeon

Comment: If you'd explain your code a little bit better that might help. What's your intention, how are you trying to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from a simple test I wrote a while back. As others have mentioned, don't change values on an active board while still reading them. Instead, clone the board and make changes to the copy while reading the current board.

Another problem I bumped into a few times was iterating over y, then x for each y, but referring to x,y when accessing a point. It feels back to front :)

```
// Rules:
// 1) Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
// 2) Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
// 3) Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
// 4) Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
void mutateGrid() {

    // Copy existing grid into the next generation's grid
    boolean[][] mutatedGrid = new boolean[gridXWidth][gridYHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < gridXWidth; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(grid[i], 0, mutatedGrid[i], 0, gridYHeight);
    }
    // Start mutation rules
    for (int y = 0; y < gridYHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridXWidth; x++) {
            int liveNeighbours = countLiveNeighbours(x,y);
            if (liveNeighbours < 2 || liveNeighbours > 3) {
                mutatedGrid[x][y] = false;
            }
            else if (liveNeighbours == 3) {
                mutatedGrid[x][y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    grid = mutatedGrid;
}

int countLiveNeighbours(int x, int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++) {
        for (int i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++) {
            if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= gridXWidth || j >= gridYHeight){
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[i][j]) {
                count++; 
            }
        }
    }
    count -= grid[x][y]?1:0; // remove self from count
    return count;
}
```